# retrofit I periodically get the error No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I periodically receive complaints from users that the application is working, they sent records on which it is clear that the Internet is available but the application does not receive data, added error logging for which I see that the error is "Unable to resolve host "site.ru": No address associated with hostname"
I managed to catch such an error by turning off and on the mobile Internet and at some point the Internet is on and there is no access to it from the application, although if you open this URL from the same device in the browser, then it all works. Closing and opening the application does not help, it helps to either wait 5 minutes or close the application, turn off and turn on the Internet and open the application again.

I've looked at many threads on the forum but haven't been able to find an answer on how to fix this.

code retrofit

```
object NetworkService {
    const val BASE_URL_API = "https://sait.ru/"       
    private var mInstance: NetworkService = NetworkService
    private var mContext: Context? = null

    val gson = GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create()
    private var mRetrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL_API)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .callFactory(getOkHTTPClient())
        .build()
    fun getInstanceRetrofit(): NetworkService {
        return mInstance
    }

    fun getOkHTTPClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
                override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                    val request = chain.request()
                    val response: Response
                    try {
                        response = chain.proceed(request)
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        setError(e , request.url)
                        throw IOException("Network error", e)
                    }
                    return response
                }
            })
        return client.build()
    }

     fun setError(t: IOException, url: HttpUrl) {
         val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
             mContext!!,
             AppDatabase::class.java, "database-file-name.db"
         ).build()

         val current = LocalDateTime.now()
         var logError = Log(0, current.toString() + url.toString() + t.message, 0)

         GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
             db.logDao().insert(logError)
         }
    }

    fun getJSONApi1(context: Context): NetworkAPI {
        mContext = context
        return mRetrofit.create(NetworkAPI::class.java)
    }

}
```

call

```
NetworkService.getInstanceRetrofit().getJSONApi(applicationContext)
            .login(login, password, pin, fcmToken).enqueue(object: Callback<Token> {
                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Token>, response: Response<Token>) {
                    if(response.isSuccessful && response.code() == 200){
                        // ....
                    }
                }

                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Token>, t: Throwable) {
                    textError!!.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    textError!!.text = "Ошибка соединения с интернетом"
                }
            })
```

I tried to recreate mInstance when I got an error, this helped to some extent, now you don’t need to reconnect the Internet, but the request may not start working on the first try

```
object NetworkService {
    const val BASE_URL_API = "https://site.ru/"       
    private var mInstance: NetworkService? = null
    private var mContext: Context? = null

    val gson = GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create()
    private var mRetrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL_API)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
        .callFactory(getOkHTTPClient())
        .build()
    fun getInstanceRetrofit(): NetworkService {
        if (mInstance == null)
        {
            mInstance = NetworkService
        }
        return mInstance!!
    }

    fun getOkHTTPClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(object : Interceptor {
                override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
                    val request = chain.request()
                    val response: Response
                    try {
                        response = chain.proceed(request)
                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        setError(e , request.url)
                        mInstance = null
                        throw IOException("Network error", e)
                    }
                    return response
                }
            })
        return client.build()
    }

     fun setError(t: IOException, url: HttpUrl) {
         val db = Room.databaseBuilder(
             mContext!!,
             AppDatabase::class.java, "database-file-name.db"
         ).build()

         val current = LocalDateTime.now()
         var logError = Log(0, current.toString() + url.toString() + t.message, 0)

         GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
             db.logDao().insert(logError)
         }
    }

    fun getJSONApi(context: Context): NetworkAPI {
        mContext = context
        return mRetrofit.create(NetworkAPI::class.java)
    }
}
```